# What is faster, one complicated regular expression, or many smaller ones?

Tags: javascript, regex, scalability

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have /[0-9]+/ problems.

I am attempting to replace certain character combinations in a paragraph (of indeterminate length) with newer text. The character combinations can get fairly complicated, so much so that the regex is this beast:

```
/&gt;:\)|\([\w~]+\)|\\[:]?[od]\/|[:;\|bBiIxX8\(\)\]][=\-"^:]?[)>$&|\w\(\)*@#?]?[)>$&|\w\(\)*@#?]/g
```

It contains six different "clauses" (is that the right word?) separated by a pipe.

Would this regular expression be better split up into six smaller regular expressions, or would the overhead of running `.replace()` on the same paragraph six times negate any benefit (if at all)?

Comment: How are you running that regex? `var re = /..../; re.exec('string')` or `string.match(/..../)` type thing? Depending on the JS implementation, the regex might get compiled ONCE, or repeatedly.

Comment: I am using `.replace()` and passing a function into the second argument to handle the matches (and return replacements)

Comment: You can reduce your pattern to: `/&gt;:\)|\([\w~]+\)|\\:?[od]\/|[]:;|bBiIxX8()][="^:-]?[)>$&|\w(*@#?]{1,2}/g`

Answer (score 0):

The avantage of using `regexp` is that you can pre-compiled them like explain in [this](http://www.levihackwith.com/javascript-performance-tip-precompile-your-regular-expressions/) post.

In this post, you can see that `regexp` perf decrease if you use your regular expressions repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks @JoDev, will definitely precompile the regular expression for repeated calls to `.replace()`